# jQuery Promise loading one html page after another

Tags: jquery, promise

I want to load one html page inside another html page using jQuery Promises. But could not load. Below is the code ..

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function() {

 var loadPageLoaded = function(){ return $('div.loadContainer').load('load.html').promise();}
 var loadAwardsPage = function(){ return $('div#maincontainer').load('assets/templates/awards.html').promise();}


loadPageLoaded().then(loadAwardsPage());


});
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the promise objects and use `$.when()` to find out if those promises are fulfilled. like this example

```
function createPromise( baseInfoTemplate ) {
    var baseData = { /* foobar */ };

    return $.Deferred(function( promise ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#foo').append('<li>' + baseInfoTemplate + ' --> success</li>');
            promise.resolve();
        }, ~~(Math.random() * 8000));
    }).promise();
}

var myPromises = [ ];

myPromises.push( createPromise( 'some data' ) );
myPromises.push( createPromise( 'even moar data' ) );
myPromises.push( createPromise( 'foo bar heay' ) );
myPromises.push( createPromise( 'hey yooo' ) );
myPromises.push( createPromise( 'who wants some?' ) );

$.when.apply( null, myPromises ).done( function() {
    $('#foo').append('<li class="last">all done!</li>');
});
```

Here using `.apply()` because it accepts an array as arguments for a function call. So in this case, we're passing all promises objects to `.when()`.

**Here an Example** [JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg77A/1/)

Comment: Either ways I don't see the xhr request for the second load in my browser dev tools

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me, Code was fine but it was issue with amount of time taken to load the first page. And second page could only load after 2-3 seconds.

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var loadPageLoaded = function(){ return $('div.loadContainer').load('load.html').promise();}
    var loadAwardsPage = function(){
      var maincontainer = $('div#maincontainer');
      return $.Deferred(function( promise ) {
            maincontainer.load('assets/templates/awards.html');
            promise.resolve();
      }).promise();
    }
    loadPageLoaded().done(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        loadAwardsPage();
      }, 2000)
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

`then` takes functions as arguments (one for onResolved, the second for onRejected)

Your code is executing and `loadPageLoaded()` and `loadAwardsPage()` immediately ... the result (a promise) is being passed to .then as it's argument ... but .then ignores anything that isn't a function - hence no error

The simple solution is to pass the function `loadAwardsPage` as an argument to `.then` - i.e. remove the `()`

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var loadPageLoaded = function() {
            return $('div.loadContainer').load('load.html').promise();
        }
        var loadAwardsPage = function() {
            return $('div#maincontainer').load('assets/templates/awards.html').promise();
        }
        loadPageLoaded().then(loadAwardsPage);
    });
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: This did not work, by the time I am at line 7 the DOM is not ready with $('div#maincontainer'), where as If I do a setTimeout for few seconds . It works.